# Problems computing a score of two lists in python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, data-structures

Let's say I have two lists, both lists have the same number of elements (sublists):

```
list_1 = [['Hi my name is anon'],
                 ['Hi I like #hokey'],
                 ['Hi I like hokey'],
                 ['Hello guys'],
                 .....
                 ['Thanks for the help']]


list_2 = [['Hi my name is anon_2'],
                 ['Hi I like #Basketball'],
                 ['Hi I like hokey'],
                 ['Hello guys'],
                 ....
                 ['Thanks for the support']]
```

I would like to compute the [distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Distance/) between the first sublist of `list_1` and the first sublist of `list_2` and so on until n-1 and place the scores in a new list (i.e. get the score in this way: from `list_1`, `sublist_1` vs. from `list_2`, `sublist_1` and so on until n-1)

This is what I tried, with a map:

```
import distance as dis

scores_list = list(set(map(dis.jaccard(list_of_lists_1,list_of_lists_2) )))
print scores_list
```

But get this traceback:

```
test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    scores_list = set(map(dis.jaccard(list_of_lists_1,list_of_lists_2) ))
  File "test.py", line 33, in jaccard
    set1, set2 = set(seq1), set(seq2)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would like to get a list like this:

```
scores_list = [score_1, score_2,score_3,score_4,score_5]
```

Comment: something is up in you dis.jaccard. You are trying to create a set from a multi-dimensional collection. Better read up on "set" in the python docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have a list of list of strings. To get rid of the inner lists, you can use a lambda

```
strings_1 = [i[0] for i in list_1]
strings_2 = [i[0] for i in list_2]
```

Edit:

If you are trying to compare each pair of strings, you would do

```
scores_list = [dis.jaccard(i,j) for i,j in zip(strings_1, strings_2)]
```

I prefer the above list comprehension, but if you did want to use `map`, you would use something like this

```
scores_list = list(map(dis.jaccard, zip(strings_1, strings_2)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got this trace: `, line 24, in <module>
    scores_list = list(set(map(dis.jaccard(strings_1, strings_2))))
TypeError: map() requires at least two args` in addition I would like to compare the **sublists** of `list_1` and `list_2`  not both (i.e. not list_1 and list_2 as a whole)

Comment: @skwoi I think I get what you are shooting for, see my edit if that is what you're after

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension with `zip`

```
scores_list = [dis.jaccard(val1[0], val2[0]) for val1, val2 in zip(list_1, list_2)]
```